# Upgrading to springframework.scheduling.concurrent?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

As of Spring 3.0 the ScheduledTimerTask is deprecated and I can't understand how to upgrade to org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.

```
    <bean id="timerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
            <list>
                 <ref bean="onlineTimeSchedule" />
            </list>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="onlineTimeSchedule" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
        <property name="timerTask" class="com.example.OnlineTimerTask" />
        </property>
        <property name="period" value="60000" />
        <property name="delay" value="1000" />
    </bean>
```

Where the OnlineTimerTask extends java.util.TimerTask. It's simple task which publishes a message to publisher every minute. I checked the documentation, but nothing.. I can't understand which way to use from the concurrent package and which suits the best.

Also I want to turn this xml into @Bean in Java.

**EDIT:** So I tried to implement the xml with @Bean and @Configuration instead and here is what I got.

```
@Configuration
public class ContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean scheduledExecutorFactoryBean() {
        ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean scheduledFactoryBean = new ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean();
        scheduledFactoryBean.setScheduledExecutorTasks(new ScheduledExecutorTask[] {onlineTimeSchedule()});

        return scheduledFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduledExecutorTask onlineTimeSchedule() {
        ScheduledExecutorTask scheduledTask = new ScheduledExecutorTask();
        scheduledTask.setDelay(1000);
        scheduledTask.setPeriod(60000);
        scheduledTask.setRunnable(new OnlineTimerTask());

        return scheduledTask;
    }
}
```

Will the code above be correct replacement for xml? Will in my case the setScheduledExecutorTasks work properly? I mean will the referencing to the same bean instance, if onlineTimeSchedule() is called more than once, will work here?

```
scheduledFactoryBean.setScheduledExecutorTasks(new ScheduledExecutorTask[] {onlineTimeSchedule()});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` in place of `org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean` and use `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask` in place of `org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask`.  You will need to adjust the property names and values as needed but, that should be pretty self evident.

Optionally, you could refactor your `com.example.OnlineTimerTask` to not extend `java.util.TimeTask` as the ScheduledTimerTask only requires a runnable.

Comment: @Richards Correct, the executor's do not require tasks be TimerTask instances.  They merely need to implement Runnable.

Comment: You have a typo there, that's why i said it. However, yea, removed the TimerTask. What does the fixedRate mean? I did set the period, delay and task, but can't figure out the point of fixedRate.

Comment: Trying to do as you said i get this: Error creating bean with name 'timerFactoryBean' defined in ... Cannot resolve reference to bean 'onlineTimeSchedule' while setting bean property 'scheduledExecutorTasks' with key [0]; nested exception is ... BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onlineTimeSchedule' defined in ...

Comment: Error setting property values; nested exception is ... NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'executorTask' of bean class ... ScheduledExecutorTask: Bean property 'executorTask' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: @Brent - What to use in place of org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean

Comment: @Anjanaa Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825827/methodinvokingtimertaskfactorybean-is-deprecated-what-class-should-i-be-using-i help answer your question?

Answer (score 7):

Spring 4 configuration - Below configuration working after spring  migration from 3.2.x to 4.6.x

```
<bean id="schedulerTask"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="springJmsListnerContainer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="timerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <property name="runnable" ref="schedulerTask" />
        <property name="delay" value="100" />
        <property name="period" value="60000" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledExecutorTasks">
            <list>
                <ref bean="timerTask" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is -  add one "runnable" field

```
 <bean id="scheduledExecutorTask" 
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
    <!-- wait 10 milli seconds before starting repeated execution -->
    <property name="delay">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <!-- run every 1 second -->
    <property name="period">
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="runnable">
        <ref bean="checkInvokingTask"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```