# Alternate for ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We upgraded spring version of our project from 3.2.7 to 4.0.6 and found that  org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean class is no more  exists spring 4.0.6. I tried the solution mentioned here [stackOverflowSolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369246/upgrading-to-springframework-scheduling-concurrent)   . But it  is not working for me.

Here is what i tried. In one of context xml I had following  bean

`<bean id="timerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
            <list>
                <!-- leave empty -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>`

As per solution mentioned in the link I changed the bean definition like below to use org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean

```
<bean id="timerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean">

    <!-- <property name="scheduledTimerTasks"> -->
    <property name="scheduledExecutorTasks">

        <list>
            <!-- leave empty-->
        </list> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

But this solution is not working  for me because Following  code is breaking because of type cast

```
  ProcessInitiatorTask timerTask = (ProcessInitiatorTask) context.getBean("initiateProcessesTask", ProcessInitiatorTask.class);
            event.getServletContext().setAttribute("CURRENT_TASK", timerTask);

            timerTask.init(config);

            // Code will break at below line
            Timer timer = (Timer) context.getBean("timerFactory", Timer.class);   
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000L, config.getPeriod().longValue() * 60 * 1000);
```

When I run this code I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'timerFactory' must be of type [java.util.Timer], but was actually of type [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor]

Please let me know what modifications I need to make to make this code work with Spring 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. In bean declaration `timerFactory` bean was declared as of type `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean`, but I was trying  to cast it to `java.util.Timer` which was wrong in first place. Then I tried to cast it to `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` which still didn't work. This is because `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` is a Spring Factory bean. Which means that it is meant to create an object of a target type but not an instance of itself. In this case target type for `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` is`org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` So I casted `timerFactory` bean to type `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` which worked. Following is the modified line of code

```
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor timer = 
       (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) context.getBean("timerFactory",
       ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.class);
```